# Cron job fails when specifying an hour

Tags: linux, cron

I have a cron job that I have been testing, and it works as long as I do not specify the hour.

for instance I will have this, which should run at 2pm, but it never runs

```
0 14 * * * /location/to/script
```

if I change the above code to run at any hour on minute zero it works. 
I have checked my system time to make sure it is correct (using date). Is there any other area I should look at to check the time? Or are their any other reasons the job might fail when i specify the hour? Thank you for any input

Comment: Have you looked for cron log entries about what might be going wrong? The might be in /var/log/cron, /var/log/syslog, ...

Comment: Did you try running another script at that timestamp, as simple as "date > /tmp/cron_was_running" ?

Comment: I made a job 34 15 * * * date >> /tmp/cron_was_running.txt and it did not run, but if i * the hour the same command works.

Comment: How do you edit this line, and in which file is it?

Comment: I would bet for a TZ (timezone) setting problem, try putting 0,6,12,18 as hour field, wait 6 hours and see if and when it was fired.

Comment: I am editing using crontab -e. I made 24 different commands (1 for each hour) to see what timezone cron was using. And at 4:00 PM CST, cron things it is 22:00.